# Creating a custom admin theme for Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm playing around with Django, and wondering if there is a link to documentation where one can get details on creating your own Django admin theme?

Comment: Searching on google for 'custom admin theme django' brings up several articles, old StackOverflow links, a pointer to The Django book and a link to Grapelli, a full-fledged and fully-branded Django admin theme.

Comment: And a search for the same will bring up this SO question. Which in turn will help people in the future who is looking for the same answer. +1 because this question does not deserve -2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Django Admin Site docs has a section on [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

[Grapelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) is the most common Django theme that I'm aware of. I recommend you have a look at the source and see how they've done it.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Grapelli](https://grappelliproject.com/), would like to add some others possible options I personally like:

- [Django Suit](https://djangosuit.com/)
- [Django Dashboard NowUI](https://appseed.us/admin-dashboards/django-dashboard-nowui) - with a [PRO version](https://appseed.us/admin-dashboards/django-dashboard-nowui-pro)

If you decide going with Django Suit, [one of my previous QAs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41641423/5675325) explains the needed steps.

If you go with Django Dashboard NowUI, you have to clone the source code ([available in GitHub](https://github.com/app-generator/django-dashboard-nowui)). That project has associated with it a requirements.txt which you have to install (i suggest in a Python venv)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Before being able to runserver, you'll need to makemigrations and migrate to generate some needed tables and that's it - that simple.

Comment: But how do you hook up the existing registered admin to the Dashboard UI?

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati https://github.com/app-generator/django-now-ui-dashboard#how-to-use-it