# Django Admin - login

Tags: python, mysql, django, powershell, django-admin

I'm building a *Django Web App with Django Suit for the administration interface*.

Already got have Python 2.7, Django 1.10, and MySQL communicating in harmony and started a project:

```
python -m django-admin startproject webapp
```

So, those were the steps made in the Windows PowerShell after that:

**1.** Start our virtual env and run the server:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd C:\PythonProjects

PS C:\PythonProjects> virtualenvs\rrh\Scripts\activate

(rrh) PS C:\PythonProjects> cd rrh/webapp
```

**2.** Setup Django Suit

```
(rrh) PS C:\PythonProjects\rrh\webapp> pip install django-suit==0.2.23
```

Then,

go to *settings.py* file and add the 'suit' application:

(this is how is looking on mine)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Also,

make sure you have `django.template.context_processors.request`,in your TEMPLATES OPTIONS context_processors (in *settings.py*):

This is required to handle left side menu.

(this is how is looking on mine)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', # Make sure you have this line
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then,

```
(rrh) PS C:\PythonProjects\rrh\webapp> ./manage.py collectstatic


(rrh) PS C:\PythonProjects\rrh\webapp> pip install git+https://github.com/darklow/django-suit.git
```

Django Suit (https://github.com/darklow/django-suit)

The folder structure is the following:

[image]

The database as the following aspect (with one row in auth_user):
[image]

This is the screen when run the command and view in the browser the result:

```
(rrh) PS C:\PythonProjects\rrh\webapp> python manage.py runserver
```

[image: admin-screen]

***The problem is:*** even though there's one user in the DB, with username and password, why am I not able to do the login?

Thank you for the help

Comment: is your user active ? check the ´is_active´ column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created a new database, a new virtualenv, installed django, started a new django admin project, did migration, created a user, installed mysql-python, migrated to mysql, installed django suite, add the specifications to installed apps and all worked perfect.

see the django procedures I went through to make this [here](https://github.com/spastnudel/Django/tree/master/procedures).

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are trying to login on a part of your website which requires administrative rights.

Did you create the user with createsuperuser in `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: created directly in the database and in the column 'is_superuser', TINYINT, entered 1 as a value.

So, should have done the same or how is it handled in Django?

Comment: I know TINYINT is bad database design because it's goes from 0 to 255. Actually don't know why Django does that to be honest

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen if you directly insert a user into the database. I do know that django has its own authentication layer and that there might be some magic happening there. Maybe add one through the shell and see what is different between those users in the database?

This is what you should insert in the shell:
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')`

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Use an enter after `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, then `User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'pass')`

Comment: Oh I just found out that you can also just use the command `./manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: created the user and still can't login.
BTW in the database introduced in the exact same way, the only difference was the password is now encrypted

Comment: What do you see in the terminal of ./manage.py runserver when you attempt to login? Can you also try to access an admin page without installing django-suite?

Comment: [14/Jan/2017 07:36:47] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3697

. Going to start a new project in the same virtualenv. If doesn't work, will start a new virtual env and do the same.
Thank you for your time

Comment: created a new database, a new virtualenv, installed django, started a new django admin project, did migration, created a user, installed mysql-python, migrated to mysql, installed django suite, add the specifications to installed apps and all worked perfect. That was really weird what happened yesterday

Comment: Just a small note, when you create user directly in database, there is a field called is_staff which you need to set to True. That flag indicates if user can login to admin site or not.